# How to use foreach in struts

Tags: java, foreach, struts

I have this struts code where I am using forEach-

```xml
<c:forEach items="${reviewList}" var="reviewListId">
<tr>
   <td colspan="6" class="we_have"><c:out value="${reviewListId}" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

I have added this taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

But in place of `forEach` tag showing an error that is-

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions

but in place of tag lib its not showing any error that means its supporting this tag lib but don't know why its not supporting forEach tag.

Comment: which server and version of server are you using . seems like JSTL name space is wrong.

Comment: Why you haven't used logic:iterate tag. It is provided by Struts itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core prefix="c"%>`

Comment: still its not working showing
"The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

in place of taglib.

Comment: you have to specify "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" this in web.xml at taglib tag before using this

Comment: I have added 
<taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
but still its showing same massage.

Answer (score 1):

I am not knowing more about the issue without seeing the code but if its not working then another altenative which you may use is struts Iterator

`Iterator will iterate over a value. An iterable value can be any of: java.util.Collection, java.util.Iterator`

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/iterator.html

Comment: seems like this is the example of struts2 but I am using struts1.

Comment: <logic:iterate> is there in strut 1 example http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-logic-iterate-example/

Comment: But we have a class where 4 fields available and we want to show these all fields in different column so we are using forEach because its not possible in iterate.

Comment: that is list like-
customer cust=new customer();
cust.setName("name");
cust.setLastName("Last Name");

and 
reviewList.add(cust);


So I want to show this two field in two diff column.

Means this is the List of Pojo.

Comment: reviewList is he list of customer object so you can do it using this as <logic:iterate name="reviewList" id="a">
<td>name<bean:write name="a" property="name"/>
</td>
<td>name<bean:write name="a" property="lastName"/>
</td>,....
</logic:iterate>

Answer (score 1):

Please verifiy your c.tld that items attribute allow rtexprvalue,

```
    <attribute>
        <name>items</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
```

This is wrong, if the declaration like this you can't give expression. Please change rtexprvalue true and try. Better download correct version of tld file

Comment: I am using this example -

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseForEachtoLoopThroughArrayList.htm

Comment: If you have c.tld in your workspace verify "rtexprvalue" for items attribute. It should be true